# Multiple aggregations with different where clauses

Tags: sql-server, grouping, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I have a table called Entries that manages transactions for specific Units.

In entries, there is a column called Sales Source that specifies the type of sale completed. I am trying to create a table that shows the total amount of revenue made per unit per sale source type.

For example:

A unit called AB104 has 8000$ in revenue, 5000$ was made via a Phone source and 3000$ was from a Fax source. I want to display a table that shows the unit number and the amount made for each sale type in the same line.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT Unit,
       sum(MoneyIN + MoneyOUT) AS Revenue,
       sum(VolumeOUT+ VolumeIN) AS volume,
       sum(WeightOUT + WeightIN)AS weight,
       PercentageR = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)*100 /
                                               (SELECT sum(MoneyIN + MoneyOUT)
                                                FROM Entries)), 1) + '%',
       PercentageV = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,sum(VolumeIN+VolumeOUT)*100 /
                                               (SELECT sum(VolumeIN + VolumeOUT)
                                                FROM Entries)), 1) + '%',
       PercentageW = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,sum(WeightIN+WeightOUT)*100 /
                                               (SELECT sum(WeightIN + WeightOUT)
                                                FROM Entries)), 1) + '%',
       LinkRevenue=
  (SELECT sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)
   WHERE salesSource ='Link'),
       PhoneRevenue=
  (SELECT sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)
   WHERE salesSource ='Phone'),
       EmailRevenue=
  (SELECT sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)
   WHERE salesSource ='Email'),
       FaxRevenue=
  (SELECT sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)
   WHERE salesSource ='Fax'),
       NoneRevenue=
  (SELECT sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)
   WHERE salesSource ='None')
FROM Entries
GROUP BY Unit,
         SalesSource
ORDER BY Unit
```

The problem with that query however, is that it doesnt show the different types of revenues for each unit in one line. This query would output:

```
Unit | rev | vol | weight | % Revenue | % Weight | % Volume | $ Link |$Phone |$Email|$Fax |$None

AB104|5000$|22|15000| 17%| 10%|    15%| 0$|5000$|0$|0$|0$  

AB104|3000$|12|18000| 21%| 21%|    7%| 0$|0$|0$|3000$|0$
```

instead I want it to group all the details for the same unit in one line, like this:

```
Unit | rev | vol | weight | % Revenue | % Weight | % Volume | $ Link |$Phone |$Email|$Fax |$None

AB104|8000$|34|33000| 38%| 31%|    22%| 0$|5000$|0$|3000$|0$
```

How can I accomplish that? when I take salesSource out of the grouping, I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group by has two columns in it. You are seeing a Unit row for every SalesSource. You can add SalesSource as a column by itself and see.

Also, you want to avoid adding additional selects in the select clause cause your making SQL run a separate query for every result, in your case 3 queries for every result. This will make your query not very scalable.

I think you need to remove the SalesSource from you group by clause and use case statements.

```
 Sum(Case when SalesSource = 'Link' then (MoneyIn+MoneyOut) else 0 end) as LinkRevenue,
```

You can get rid of the select-in-a-select by using a common table expression:

```
 ;with totals as (
      SELECT sum(WeightIN + WeightOUT) as WeightTotal,
             sum(VolumeIN + VolumeOUT) as VolumeTotal,
             sum(MoneyIN + MoneyOUT) as MoneyTotal
      FROM Entries
 )
 SELECT Unit,
   sum(MoneyIN + MoneyOUT) AS Revenue,
   sum(VolumeOUT+ VolumeIN) AS volume,
   sum(WeightOUT + WeightIN)AS weight,
   PercentageR = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,sum(MoneyIN+MoneyOUT)*100 /
                                           totals.MoneyTotal), 1) + '%',
   PercentageV = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,sum(VolumeIN+VolumeOUT)*100 /
                                           totals.VolumeTotal), 1) + '%',
   PercentageW = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,sum(WeightIN+WeightOUT)*100 /
                                           totals.WeightTotal), 1) + '%',
   Sum(Case when SalesSource = 'Link' then (MoneyIn+MoneyOut) else 0 end) as LinkRevenue,
 ....
 FROM Entries, totals
 GROUP BY Unit
 ORDER BY Unit
```

Comment: Your welcome! Glad you got it working. Sorry i updated the final script, forgot to take the SalesSource out of the group by

Comment: sean@          That script is very efficient. Thank you for the detailed answer! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean it up with a couple more cte's, I didn't format the Money columns with the $ sign but you can add that into the final select

```
With 
--create CTE with money columns summed for the pivotcte
TotalsCTEBySource (Unit, [Revenue],  SalesSource) AS
(SELECT Unit, MoneyIn+MoneyOut ,  SalesSource FROM Entries), 
--create CTE with table grand totals for % calcs
GrandTotalsCTE ([Revenue], [Volume],[Weight]) AS 
(SELECT sum(MoneyIn+MoneyOut) , sum(VolumeIn+VolumeOut) , sum(WeightIn+WeightOut) FROM Entries), 
--create totals by unit cte
TotalsCTEByUnit (Unit, [Revenue], [Volume],[Weight]) AS
(SELECT Unit, sum(MoneyIn+MoneyOut) , sum(VolumeIn+VolumeOut) , sum(WeightIn+WeightOut)
FROM Entries GROUP BY Unit), 
--create pivot cte to get the sales source values as column headers, use coalesce() to turn NULL into 0
PivotCTE (Unit, [$ Link],[$ Phone],[$ Fax],[$ Email],[$ None])AS
(   select Unit,coalesce(sum([Link]),0), coalesce(sum([Phone]),0),coalesce(sum([Fax]),0),
    coalesce(sum([Email]),0),coalesce(sum([None]),0) FROM(
    select Unit, [Link],[Phone],[Fax],[Email],[None] from TotalsCTEBySource
        PIVOT
            (sum(Revenue)FOR SalesSource in ([Link],[Phone],[Fax],[Email],[None])) pivottable 
    ) moneybygroup
group by Unit   )

--bring it all together
SELECT t.Unit, t.Revenue, t.Volume, t.Weight,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),round(t.Revenue/g.revenue*100,0))+' %' AS [% Revenue],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),round(t.Volume/g.Volume*100,0))+' %' AS [% Volume],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),round(t.Weight/g.Weight*100,0))+' %' AS [% Weight]
p.[$ Link],p.[$ Phone],p.[$ Fax],p.[$ Email],p.[$ None] 
FROM TotalsCTEByUnit t
Join PivotCTE p on t.unit=p.unit
join GrandTotalsCTE g on 1=1
```